# Take mouse to a point and scroll left and right Rselenium

Tags: r, rest, rselenium

I am trying to move this button left and right from [this](https://steamcharts.com/app/945360) website.
[image]

```
Library(RSelenium)
remDr <- rsDriver(port=1249L,browser = "chrome",chromever = "87.0.4280.88")
reDr <- remDr[["client"]]
url <-  "https://steamcharts.com/app/945360"
reDr$navigate(url)
```

When I see DOM and click on that scroll button and move left right translate changes(yelow highlighted below) is there any I can use it in my code and move according to my need?

[image]